# Is there an advantage to using Array.Empty vs. new List when initializing a List property?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Is there an advantage in one of these approaches over the other as far as performance?

```
public class Person
{
  public List<string> Favorites {get; set;} = new List<string>();
}
```

or

```
public class Person
{
  public List<string> Favorites {get; set;} = Array.Empty<string>().ToList();
}
```

I understand that there are advantages of using `Enumerable.Empty<>` and `Array.Empty<>` when working with these types. But I'm wondering specifically about when the property is of type `List<>`. My instinct says that both approaches ultimately allocate a List object, so they are essentially equivalent. Thanks!

Comment: One is both harder to read with irrelevant types and does extra work for no reason. The other can be reduced to `new()` in the latest C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Array.Empty<>()` is a very useful way of making empty arrays due to empty array optimization, but you can't do better than `new List()` for an empty list. `.ToList()` eventually needs to invoke a list constructor anyway; and the cheapeast list constructor is the default constructor.

So, no point in `Array.Empty<>().ToList()`.